# Copying a value to SOLines after updating the header is not persisiting

Tags: acumatica

I have a user field in the sales order header. When a user types their amount into that header, it loops through the lines and sets another user field based on that header. However, those lines are not saving their values. They are updated on the screen, but I am not sure they are updated in the cache. However, if I click on a line in the details window first, then update the value in the header, that line saves just fine and the others do not.

```
protected virtual void SOOrder_UsrMarkupPercent_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    SOOrder order = e.Row as SOOrder;
    if (order == null || (order.LastModifiedByScreenID == "CR304000" && order.OrderNbr.Trim().ToLower().Contains("<new>"))) return;

        SOOrderExt orderExt = order.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>();
        SetMarkupPercentAllLines(cache, orderExt.UsrMarkupPercent);
}

public void SetMarkupPercentAllLines(PXCache cache, decimal? percent)
{
    foreach (SOLine line in Base.Transactions.Select())
    {
        SOLineExt lineExt = line.GetExtension<SOLineExt>();
        lineExt.UsrMarkupPercent = percent;
        //cache.SetValue<SOLineExt.usrMarkupPercent>(line, percent);
    }
}
```

I tried just doing lineExt.UsrMarkupPercent = percent as well as cache.SetValue(line, percent) and cache.SetValueExt(line, percent) and nothing seems to work. I've tried using a PXSelect rather than Base.Transactions.Select() as well, but that didn't make a different. Is this not updating the cache properly do to something I am not doing?

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to update the value in cache (Ex: Base.Transactions.Update(line)) after setting the value in the extension field.

Something like this:

```
foreach (SOLine line in Base.Transactions.Select())
{
   SOLineExt lineExt = line.GetExtension<SOLineExt>();
   lineExt.UsrMarkupPercent = percent;
   Base.Transactions.Update(line);
}
```

Usually you will need to call the cache Update or cache.SetValueExt. In your commented line you had the cache of SOOrder and not Base.Transactions.Cache.SetValueExt. Using the view.Update in your case should work fine